# Slick Slider: Scroll to last slide if slider is in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I want to show a slider which should scroll to the last slide if the slider gets in the viewport.

I'm using the Slick Slider (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) for that.

```html
<html>

    <div class="slider-games">
   <div>
    <h1>Headline 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
   </div>
   <div>
    <h1>Headline 2</h1>
    <p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
   </div>
   <div>
    <h1>Headline 3</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
   </div>
   <div>
    <h1>Headline 4</h1>
    <p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
   </div>
   <div>
    <h1>Headline 5</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
   </div>
   <div>
    <h1>Headline 6</h1>
    <p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
   </div>
  </div>


</html>
```

**The slide "Headline 6" should be active.**

And here's the JS code:

```
$('.slider-games').slick({
    dots: true,
    arrows: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
});
```

I tried the attribute `rtl:true` but that's not working in my case.

And I saw that there is a method called `slickGoTo`. I guess that's what I need. But I don't know how to use it.

Also there is the unsolved problem, that the slider should scroll at the end when the slider gets in the visible area of the viewport.

Here's an example of it: https://codepen.io/cray_code/pen/mQEyma

Comment: I think your problem will be solved by adding a blank div

Comment: I don't see how that would help?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$('.fade').on('init', function(event, slick) {$(this).find(".slick-dots li").last().trigger("click"); });

**Just keep this before your slick slider code and else everything is perfect**

Comment: I added this to my code (before the slider code) but it's not working?! :-(

Comment: your css is different .because your css containt the classes like slik-dots , li .But in your html you did not use thes classes .So that it is not working for your code.I am directly triggering .So when you mouse drag it is firing in case of my html

Comment: If I change the class `.fade` to the class of my slider, it works! But the site jumps directly to the slider what I don't want. Is there any chance to skip the jump and start the scrolling when the slider enters the visible area of the viewport?

Answer (score 0):

Here another example I am providing

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Now Amazing Webpage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.11/slick.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <div class="fade">
        <div>
            <h1>Headline 1</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1>Headline 2</h1>
            <p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1>Headline 3</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1>Headline 4</h1>
            <p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1>Headline 5</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1>Headline 6</h1>
            <p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.11/slick.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.fade').slick({
                dots: true,
                infinite: true,
                speed: 700,
                autoplay: true,
                autoplaySpeed: 2000,
                arrows: false,
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1
            });

        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But your solution doesn't solve my problem. It doens't scroll to the last slide when the slider gets in the visible area of the viewport.

Comment: If provide the whole programe I may try

Answer (score 0):

```
$( window.top ).scroll( function () {
    var windowHeight = $( window.top ).height();
    var scrolledHeight = $( window.top ).scrollTop();
    var sliderPosition = $( window.top.document ).find( ".slider-games" ).offset().top;
    var sliderheight = $( window.top.document ).find( ".slider-games" ).height();
    if ( ( windowHeight + scrolledHeight ) > ( sliderPosition + ( sliderheight / 2 ) ) ) {
        $('.slider-games').slick('slickGoTo', $('.slider-games').get(0).slick.$slides.length-1);
    }
} );
```

This finds out the position of your slider on the page and once you scrolled past 50% of the element, it will scroll to the last slide. To trigger the scroll event from jquery, you need to be able to scroll. Instead of the scroll event you can create a timer aswell.